# word request: support in getting tasks completed

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an acknowledgments page for my dissertation, and I want to say something like "I am grateful to my family for their emotional, financial, and [some word] support throughout this process." The missing word means something like they helped me get tasks done. For example, my parents helped me move to a new state for school, and my husband took on way more than his fair share of household chores while I was working late.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about "practical support"?

Comment: I was going to suggest "hands-on", but "practical" is more in line with *emotional* and *financial.*

Comment: *Support*, by its very definition, means being helpful and enabling. To say *helpful support* would be redundant. (Unless it's used specifically to say that well-intended support was *not* helpful.) So—why not just say *emotional and financial support*?

Answer (score -1):

I think "**motivational**" support is fitting. Perhaps "**guiding**" support is another possibility.

> "I am grateful to my family for their emotional, financial, and
>   **motivational** support throughout this process."
>
> "I am grateful to my family for their emotional, financial, and
>   **guiding** support throughout this process."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/motivational

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/guiding

Comment: How does either of them indicate "they helped me get tasks done"; "helped me move to a new state for school"; "my husband took on way more than his fair share of household chores"? None of those is "guiding" or "motivational" - they are "practical" issues.

Comment: Help comes in many forms. Providing motivation and guidance are not to be overlooked.

Comment: I don't dispute your comment: what I was questioning was how your suggestions fit with OP's request for a word that covered the areas mentioned in my previous comment.